# Freeform Composer spam prevention recommendations?

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, spam, captcha

I'm using Composer to create my form and the Channel Entry Fieldtype (http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/channel_entry_fieldtype) to output it. Works great and is so simple. But a spambot just made it through the Captcha field I used (the default EE one), so I'm wondering what spam prevention you guys can recommend?

I've also used HonEEpot (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/hon-ee-pot-captcha) with success, but using the channel entry fieldtype, I'm not sure how to insert that into my form.

Comment: It looks like they are both compatible: https://github.com/davist11/Hon-ee-Pot-Captcha#freeform-forms

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't appear under my FreeForm Pro "Field Types" list, which are the field types available to Composer. I'm guessing the compatibility is if you are manually putting together your form using freeform:form.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution ended up being Snaptcha: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/snaptcha.

I was originally thinking I'd add a custom field to Composer the same way you add EE's default captcha, but with snaptcha it automatically adds itself inside your form tag and (I assume) just works. Really convenient: just enable and all of your forms get it.

Comment: Yep. Snaptcha is an automatic install on every EE site for me.